# How to call a method from a static class in another class?

Tags: java, static-methods

I have a method "b(Class g)" in a static class "a"

so
myclass.java contains...

```
public static class a{

     public void b(Class g){
     ....
     }

}
```

than another method in the same myclass.java

```
public void c(){

if(...){}
else{
   b();  //i want to call b but i get an error asking me to create the method

}
```

Comment: change it to public static void b(...);  Then from c(), call a.b(...);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `b` needs an argument of type `Class` that's why it is complaining.

**Update**

You also have a strange class declaration `public static class a`

As per [Java specification on Class declaration](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#15372)
Not all modifiers are applicable to all kinds of class declarations...... ***`The access modifier static pertains only to member classes`*** which means you have wrong static modifier in your public class declaration.

Change you top level class declaration to `public class a` first and then see how it behaves.

Comment: still asks to create a method

Comment: you also need a reference to an object of type a to call b on as the b method isn't static.

Comment: You need to change it to `a.b();`, and as @MeBigFatGuy said, change b() to static.  You must specify what class contains the method you want to call.

Comment: i want to call b from class a

Comment: @user570098: Please see the `Update` section for more explanation.

Comment: @anubhava: What is wrong in declaring a nested class as public static?

Comment: @Suresh Kumar: If it is a nested class then it can be static but a top-level class cannot be static.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to note:
1) Even though the inner class 'a' is declared static, the method `b(Class g)` is not static. So in order to access the b(Class g) method of class 'a', you still need to create an instance of 'a' i.e.

```
a a1 = new a();
a1.b(SomeClass.class);
```

Important: Declaring a class static doesn't make the methods of that class static.

2) When invoking the method `b(Class g)`, you need to pass the Class argument. Calling `b();` with no argument will result in error.

If you want to call `b(Class g)` without creating an instance of class 'a', then mark the method `b(Class g)` to be static. i.e.

```
public static class a{

     static public void b(Class g){
     ....
     }

}
```

To get a better understanding of static nested class, read [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)